# Auto-attack behavior relative to ability use

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In HotS, how is auto attack triggered or suppressed relative to use of an ability? I have seen posts suggesting that auto attack timers are reset following use of an ability and, importantly, that auto attack occurs when the timer is reset (at time 0). This would suggest that not only do abilities with short cooldowns result in more damage from those abilities, but also increases effective attack speed from auto attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto attack timer is NOT reset following the use of an ability, unless that ability specifically has that capacity.

E.T.C., for instance, had a level 7 talent prior to the May 12, 2015 patch called "Guitar Hero", which expressly stated "After using Guitar Solo, your next Basic Attack strikes immediately". If auto attack timers were reset on ability usage, this would have been 1) redundant information and 2) not actually part of the talent.

Comment: Given this information, does one need to 'wait' for an autoattack to occur before using an ability if auto-attacks are desired or will autoattacks occur regardless of what abilities are being triggered?

Comment: If you want to maximize DPS, yes, waiting to attack, pop an ability, then auto-attack again is the most efficient method.